# position: absolute causes overflow on the page

Tags: css

The question in a nutshell: codepen.io/anon/pen/OBRoNW when I shrink the page beyond the size of the blue rectangle + the green rectangles the ones on the bottom push the page down and the ones on the right push the page right so scrollbars appear. how do I prevent the pushing when it comes to position: absolute elements? also, If possible, how do I do the opposite and apply the pushing to the top left items?

The question itself (this was not completely understood so I added the simpler question on the top):
When I use position absolute, the element still takes space when it comes to the body of the page.
for instance:

```
  <div class="content">
    <div class="decoration">
    </div>
  </div>


<style>

.content{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background:blue;
  position:relative;
}
.decoration{
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
  background:green;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-5px;    
}

</style>
```

If I resize the window to the very point where a scrollbar appears then I set the `.decoration` class to `bottom:0;` the scrollbar disappears.
The behavior I expect is for the page to ignore position absolute elements when calculating the size of the page as they are not supposed to take up any space.
Therefore when the window Is shrunk it should display only half of the decoration.
Is this a bug? Is there a known solution to this?

edit: it appears to be happening only on `bottom` and `right` positioning

Comment: Actually this is overflow, and it's not related to size calculation ... add overflow:hidden to `.content` and the overflow will get hidden ... even if elements are out of the normal flow they are still considered when calculating the overflow even if not consiered to calcuate sizes

Comment: `edit: it appears to be happening only on bottom and right positioning` --> This is also by design, only right bottom overflow are visible, the other no

Comment: You can set the body to have `overflow: hidden`. But then all content that happens to overflow will be clipped as well, and hidden from the user.

Answer (score 2):

The *DOM flow* ignores the absolutely positioned element.  The space the entire *page* takes is different from the DOM flow.

Put another way: the browser is going to attempt to make it possible for a visitor to view content outside the viewport, even if it's positioned absolutely or fixed.

You should expect scrollbars any time you position anything "off" the viewport to the right or the bottom.  Positioning things off the *left* side of the page will not cause a scrollbar, and is an often-used trick for things like drop-down navigation.

**Your Original Example:**

```css
.content {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.decoration {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="decoration">
  </div>
</div>
```

**An example with left absolute positioning:**

```css
.content {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.decoration {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="decoration">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `left: -999em;` ? Isn't it better to use ` display: none; `? I oversimplified my question in order to focus on the problematic part but I will edit it to make it more specific. here is what I added to the question : A. the positioning is now bottom:-5px B. "Therefore when the window Is shrunk it should display only half of the decoration."

Comment: It doesn't matter _where_ you put it.  You can put it -5px or -5000px off the bottom, the browser viewport is going to be sure to display it.  It's not a bug, it's on purpose.  As for the `left: -999em` - mostly for screen readers, but there can be other reasons: https://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the problem is in the .decoration?
You have a fixed size container, check if you're going to resize your window smaller than 300x300px.

Anyway you can try to use `box-sizing: border-box;` as property to eventually calculate every margin/padding of divs into their respective sizes.

**EDIT** ok, I noticed that if you fixed position the div you don't get a scrollbar. Here's the codepen: [codepen example](https://codepen.io/ThoughtsRiff/pen/oazPBN)

```
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

I added a container, I was trying to achieve in another way. Anyway, if you opt for the position: fixed and want to center the div, you can use the "transform: translate" with "left: 50%" and "top: 50%" as I did in the codepen.

Comment: what do you mean by "take a window"?

Comment: I mean, @RemotH, check if your window is smaller than 300x300px when you resize it and get the scrollbar.

Comment: It is. I want it to be. what should I do in that case? I want specifically position absolute elements to be disregarded.

Comment: Can you explain, more accurately, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to have a star image on the very corner of a div (most of the star is outside the div) and when the window resizes to the size of the div I want the star to be ignored by the window and not to create a scroll so that the window will reach exactly to the size of the div.

Comment: If you don't need to scroll the page (if it's static and you have static sized elements which fits in the screen) you can try to set "overflow: hidden;" to the body. Anyway, a codpen/fiddle to see what's going on would be better to understand.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OBRoNW the ones on the bottom push the page down and the ones on the right push the page right. how to I the pushing when it comes to position: absolute elements? also, If possible, how do I do the opposite and apply the pushing to the top left items?

Comment: doesnt let me edit and copy pasting ruined my reply so: codepen.io/anon/pen/OBRoNW when I shrink the page beyond the size of the blue rectangle + the green rectangles the ones on the bottom push the page down and the ones on the right push the page right so scrollbars appear. how do I prevent the pushing when it comes to position: absolute elements? also, If possible, how do I do the opposite and apply the pushing to the top left items?

Comment: I edited my answer and inserted a codepen, check it.

Comment: Thats a very cool observation but unfortunately it doesnt apply in my case. Thank you very much anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `<body>` element to have `overflow: hidden`. But then all other content that happens to overflow will be clipped as well, and the user won't be able to see it.

```
body {
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

If you have a section on the page that needs overflow prevented on the right, for example, you can just set `overflow: hidden` to that section.